# MCP3008 inconsistent reading

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

Okay, I've written a small piece of code for reading analog values from MCP3008 and it all works good I would say. But the problem is, the value changes depending on a frequency of which I'm reading them. Any ideas what could cause such behaviour?

**Update:** Here's my code. Maybe I did something wrong...

```
enum {
    MCP3008_RESOLUTION = 1024,
    MCP3008_CONFIG_LO = 0x80,
    MCP3008_CONFIG_HI = 0x01
};
uint16_t MCP3008::Read(uint8_t channel)
{
    if (channel > 7)
        throw "Out of range.";

    uint8_t writeBuffer[] = { MCP3008_CONFIG_LO, MCP3008_CONFIG_HI | (channel << 4), 0x00 };
    auto readBuffer = ref new Array<uint8_t>(3);

    _device->TransferFullDuplex(ref new Array<uint8_t>(writeBuffer, 3), readBuffer);

    uint16_t buf = readBuffer[2];
    buf += (readBuffer[1] & 0x03) << 8;
    return buf;
}

void MCP3008::CreateDevice(Platform::String ^ friendlyName, uint8_t chipSelectLine,
    Windows::Devices::Spi::SpiMode mode, uint32_t dataBitLength, uint32_t clockFrequency)
{
    Platform::String^ aqs;
    if (friendlyName)
        aqs = SpiDevice::GetDeviceSelector(friendlyName);
    else
        aqs = SpiDevice::GetDeviceSelector();

    auto dis = concurrency::create_task(
        DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(aqs)).get();
    if (dis->Size < 1)
        throw "SPI Initialization failed. Could not find SPI controller.";

    auto id = dis->GetAt(0)->Id;

    auto settings = ref new Windows::Devices::Spi::SpiConnectionSettings(chipSelectLine);
    if (int(mode) != -1)
        settings->Mode = mode;
    if (dataBitLength)
        settings->DataBitLength = dataBitLength;
    if (clockFrequency)
        settings->ClockFrequency = clockFrequency;

    _device = concurrency::create_task(
        SpiDevice::FromIdAsync(id, settings)).get();

    if (!_device)
        throw "SPI Initialization failed. Device is already in use.";
}
```

Comment: What sensor(s) are you using? Can you add your code to your question? What do you mean the values are changing with the frequency? I would expect certain types of sensors to vary on every reading.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I've added the code. It's actually a voltage meter I'm building. Just a simple voltage divider and ADC. But when I'm reading the value 10 times per second it gives me `256` for example, but on the other side when I'm reading it 20 times per second it gives me `128`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what happens when you read it once or twice a second

Comment: What is with the ^ in this line? void MCP3008::CreateDevice(Platform::String ^ friendlyName, uint8_t chipSelectLine,

Comment: Gimme like 5 minutes I'll check that out!

Comment: It's UWP symbol for `handle` to a `string`

Comment: sorry didn't realize we were on windows thought this was C not C#

Comment: once per second: 576
twice per second: 147
Measured with 2.4V (ref 3V3)
Sorry It took longer than I expected

Comment: Can you share the code where you do the periodic reading as well?

Comment: @RonBeyer Since I've created a new project for testing purposes, I'm using while loop with sleep at the end.

Comment: Sounds like timing issues. Possibly something not being calculated properly or compensated for. First of all, establish which config gives you the correct reading. Then you can work out what is causing the erratic numbers by debugging.